# View shifts down when presenting view controller with status bar on iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uistoryboard, uistatusbar

I have a view controller (view1) that prefers a hidden status bar. I have a button that presents another view controller (view2) modally from the bottom of the screen (a 'Show' segue in my storyboard) and view2 prefers a visible status bar. On iOS 8, this is a smooth transition from view1 to view2, but on iOS 9 the status bar immediately appears in view1 when I press the button and the entire view of view1 shifts down to accommodate it.

This is an ugly effect and I wish to avoid it. For some reason iOS 8 handles this much more gracefully than iOS 9. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, you can set a global variable on view2 as

```
isStatusBarHidden = false
```

on viewWillAppear of view2 change it to true and update status bar

```
isStatusBarHidden = true
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

the status bar delegate function will look like

```
func prefersStatusBarHidden() {
    return isStatusBarHidden
}
```

this only works in Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: Good tip. On 9.3 and 10.1, I also needed to wrap the `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` call in an animation block.